# Why is this prgram not working in C?

Tags: c

I program doesn't work after entering P or A. why?
it's challenge from udemy course. I am just a beginner in programming :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float height=0;
    float width=0;
    float area=0;
    float perimeter=0;
    printf("Enter height of rectangle :");
    scanf("%f",&height);
    printf("Enter width of rectangle :");
    scanf("%f", &width);

    char choice;
    printf("Enter P for perimeter and A for area: ");
    scanf(" %c", choice);
    if(choice=='P' || choice=='p'){       
        printf("Width: %f", width);
        printf("Height: %f", height);
        perimeter= 2.0*(height*width);
        printf("Perimeter of rectangle is: %f", perimeter);
    }else if(choice=='A' || choice=='a'){
        printf("Width: %f", width);
        printf("Height: %f", height);
        area= (height*width);
        printf("Area of rectangle is: %f", area);
    }else
        printf("Invalid Input");
}
```

Comment: Perimeter is not `2.0*(height*width)`

Answer (score 0):

Correct this as follows:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

&choice will point to an address where you want to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working Because you forgot `&` in `scanf(" %c", choice);` . It should be `scanf(" %c", &choice);` . In `scanf` function , you have to provide the address of the item to be scanned *(Similar to scanf("%f", &height);).*

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float height = 0;
    float width = 0;
    float area = 0;
    float perimeter = 0;
    printf("Enter height of rectangle :");
    scanf("%f", &height);
    printf("Enter width of rectangle :");
    scanf("%f", &width);

    char choice;
    printf("Enter P for perimeter and A for area: ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    if (choice == 'P' || choice == 'p')
    {
        printf("Width: %f", width);
        printf("Height: %f", height);
        perimeter = 2.0 * (height * width);
        printf("Perimeter of rectangle is: %f", perimeter);
    }
    else if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
    {
        printf("Width: %f", width);
        printf("Height: %f", height);
        area = (height * width);
        printf("Area of rectangle is: %f", area);
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid Input");
}
```

**Output :-**

```
Enter height of rectangle :4
Enter width of rectangle :5
Enter P for perimeter and A for area: A
Width: 5.000000Height: 4.000000Area of rectangle is: 20.000000
```

I recommend to add `\n` before your `printf()`  statements for better readability.

Comment: but we are not suppose to use & symbol while entering character or string. I show that line somewhere I don't remember though

Comment: We are supposed to use `&` for character @HrithikAgrawal . Only in the case of strings , we don't use `&`